# Adding JavaScript to the header tag in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, header

For performance testing & monitoring, I would like to add a JavaScript in the header tag of a web pages. All pages comes from a Java application running on Tomcat 7.

Is that possible? If yes, how do I do that?

Comment: Are you able to access the web page source code?

Comment: Well - not sure what you mean with access to the "web page source code". But since I'm hosting the Java application and its underlaying Tomcat, OS and network by myself, I would say the answer is yes.

Comment: And why were you not able to edit the `<head>` content of your web pages then?

Comment: I'm not a developer so this may sound somewhat stupid:
From where I stand, a Java application behaves very much like a CMS. In the sense that it generates web pages dynamically based on the user actions. The difference compared to a real CMS is:
(1) - The language on the serverside: typically a CMS runs on PHP (versus Java).
(2) - A Java application is targeted for a specific set of tasks (as opposed to 'a' website)

So even when I host the website & Java app myself, I'm not aware of being able to change to <head> content due to the behavior described above.

Hence starting the topic here!

Comment: If one develops a dynamic web page with Java, there are two main different approaches: Generate the resulting HTML code completely from Java source code, or use a template engine which replaces certain parts of predefined HTML pages with dynamic content - but it is common in both cases, that the developer of the application should be able to extend certain static code parts, like the `<head>` section of generated HTML with JavaScript code.

Comment: Well - although I host Apache + Tomcat and have access to all the sources, I'm not a developer nor do I have access to developers that understand these things. Hence, I started this topic.

So would you be able to outline the steps to make this happen? Or point me to some documentation that I could use to start a try-on-error type of process?